# Not able to pass an argument in onclick function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass an argument in `onclick` function but it is showing undefined in ReactJS.

My code ([or here](http://pastebin.com/cA0emJr7)):

```
var Tablelist = React.createClass({
  createNewoder: function(iid) {
    var tbn = this.iid;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        // Accept : "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        // console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      tablelist : []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/restaurant/table/list/10/1",
      headers: {
        Accept : "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      success: function(tablelist) {
        this.setState({tablelist: tablelist}, function(){
          console.log(this.state.tablelist);
        }.bind(this));
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  render: function(){
    var tablelist11 = [];
    var idd ;
    for(var tablenumber in this.state.tablelist){
      tablelist11.push(
        <div className="card">
        <div className="title">
          Table {this.state.tablelist[tablenumber].tablenumber}
        </div>
        <p>  Orders: <strong>{this.state.tablelist[tablenumber].count_orders} </strong></p>
        <p>  Location:{this.state.tablelist[tablenumber].location} </p>
        <p>  <a onClick={ this.createNewoder.bind(this, this.state.tablelist[tablenumber].tablenumber) }>Add</a></p>
        </div>
      );

      return (
        <div>
          {tablelist11}
        </div>
      );
    }
});

React.render(
  <Tablelist source="/restaurant/table/list/10/1" />,
  document.getElementById('list_tables')
);
```

On line 61, I am printing this `{this.state.tablelist[tablenumber].tablenumber}`, it is a numerical value and working fine, but now I want to pass this value also in `onclick` function in line no. 66, but it is giving `undefined`.

I tried different options, but it did not help.

How can I pass this value as argument in onclick function?

Comment: Try to change line no 6 from `var tbn = this.iid;` to `var tbn = iid;`  and see if it works.

Comment: thank you very much xyz, it solved the problem, you are my champs.

Comment: You are welcome, buddy.

Comment: Just as an aside, the order a for..in loop traverses an array is not guaranteed to be sequential. You should use a regular for loop up to the length of the array, Array.prototype.map, or a for..of loop if you are utilizing ES6

Comment: thanks for your comment